# Definition of continuum

Tags: general-topology

In class the teacher gave us the definition of a continuum as a metric, connected and compact space, on the book *General Topology* by Willard says that is a connected, compact and Hausdorff space, and in [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Continuum_(Topology)) only says that is a compact and connected space.

I'm confused, which is it? I can imagine how the first two could relate, since metric implies Hausdorff, and maybe they are even equivalent, I have to be honest I haven't checked that, but what about the third? It's way more general, is it wrong?

Comment: There are Hausdorff spaces that are not metrizable, for example the Sorgenfrey line (the topology on $\mathbb R$ generated by the basis $\{[a,b) : a < b\}$).

Comment: @user38584 oh! you're right, so those two can't be equivalent, however the first def can imply the second.

Comment: @AnaGalois Willard definition is more general, but most people work only with metric continuums.

Comment: @azarel Continua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a continuum means either

(1) connected compact Hausdorff, or

(2) connected compact metric.

Authors should make it clear which definition they are using.  In my papers, I use the first definition, then if I use "metric continuum" to describe a space satisfying (2).  The theory of non-metric continua is very interesting,  so that we should not limit ourselves to metric continua.  Note that many fundamental theorems in continuum theory hold for non-metric spaces, while others require metrizability (which is equivalent to second countability in compact Hausdorff spaces).  For instance, the Boundary Bumping Theorem holds in non-metric spaces, but to prove that an indecomposable continuum has more than one composant we must assume the continuum is metric.

Comment: Where can I read your papers? I am interested in results known to hold for any (not necessarily metric) continuum.